# Cast object to some class, adding functions of that class to the object

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Person {

    name: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;

    canVote(): boolean {
        return (this.country === "SomeCountry" && this.age >= 16) || (this.country === "SomeOtherCountry" && this.age >= 18);
    }

}
```

Is there any way in typescript to cast an object containing `name`, `age` and `country` attributes to be an instance of the class `Person` which I can call `canVote` on, like so? (Right now, this does not compile because `canVote` is missing)

```
let person: Person = {
    name: "SomePerson",
    age: 42,
    country: "SomeCountry"
}

console.log(person.canVote());
```

I know there are parameter properties which would allow me to do the following:

```
class Person {

    constructor(readonly name: string, readonly age: number, readonly country: string) {
    }

    canVote(): boolean {
        return (this.country === "SomeCountry" && this.age >= 16) || (this.country === "SomeOtherCountry" && this.age >= 18);
    }

}

let person = new Person("SomePerson", 42, "SomeCountry");
```

However, I imagine this would get unclear pretty fast if the number of properties increases or if I want to leave an optional property unset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface for the constructor and use it in the constructor. That way it will always keep the construction clean and you can easily extend the properties later if you wanted to.

```
interface ICharacter {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;
}

class Person {
    character: ICharacter;

    constructor(character: ICharacter) {
        this.character = character;
    }

    canVote(): boolean {
        return (this.character.country === "SomeCountry" && this.character.age >= 16)
            || (this.character.country === "SomeOtherCountry" && this.character.age >= 18);
    }
}

let character: ICharacter = {
    name: "SomePerson",
    age: 42,
    country: "SomeCountry"
};

let person: Person = new Person(character);
console.log(person.canVote());
```